# What does XORing for 2 decimal numbers mean?

Tags: xor

I know that XORing 2 decimal numbers mean that, they **binary representations are XORed**.
But what does it mean *non-mathematical sense* ?
**What significance does it have?**

Comment: I'm not clear what kind of answer you're hoping for. Do you mean is there a pattern to what happens to the numbers? Or, why xor would be useful?

Comment: NO, when I do OR or AND, I get the general sense that OR means selecting TRUE value among set of values, and AND is setting a value as TRUE iff all the values are set.But does XOR mean?

Comment: With numbers (or any other values with multiple bits) that's not what OR and AND mean at all - there isn't really any notion of "true", just "does this bit occur in one value, both, or neither?" Kind of like writing the numbers out on top of each other, and seeing how they overlap. With carefully selected values, OR can be a kind of + (and XOR a kind of -). I'm not sure how something could have "significance" for *numbers* in a "non-mathematical sense"; if it's non-mathematical, perhaps you're looking for a way of picturing the operation when the bits are *not* treated as numbers?

Answer (score 19):

If you XOR the result with one of the original numbers, you get the other original number.

```
a ^ b = X
X ^ a = b
X ^ b = a
```

This is used commonly in cryptography and hashing algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

In simple words, the XOR of two decimal means, first converting the two decimals to binary and then performing the bit-wise XOR and then again converting the result to decimal.

Let's take an example,

Suppose we wanna find out what does `3^7` results? (where `^` is symbolising XOR operation)

**Step 1** : *Converting the numbers from decimal to binary*

`3 => 0011` and  `7 => 0111`

**Step 2** : *Taking the bit-wise XOR of the two binary numbers*

```
  3  : 0011
  7  : 0111
 3^7 : 0100
```

> (hint : 1^0 = 1 and 1^1 = 0^0 = 0)

**Step 3** : *Convert the answer to decimal*

`0100 => 4`

***Hence, the 3^7 = 4***

Click [here](https://www.codechef.com/PRJRF14/problems/XORSN) for more details.

Comment: you wrote `7 => 1111`, but isn't 7 (decimal) = 0111 (binary) ?

Answer (score 2):

if i correctly understand, you are searching for the physical meaning of XOR.
xor is an odd parity counter, i mean if you xor(A,B), you are counting the number of ones in each bit, if the number is odd, the xor output will be one

Ex:
3 = 0011
5 = 0101

3 ^ 5 = 0110
in the LSB there are (1 and 1) which represent two ones, and since two is even, therefore you put 0, in the next bit, there are (1 and 0) and the count of ones is one which is odd, therefore you put 1 and so on.

if you want to experiment this, try [this online](http://xor.pw/#) calculator

this is used alot in telecommunication for parity check and in error correcting algorithms, and generation of orthogonal code sequencye; see this [website about CDMA](https://sites.google.com/site/the4gtelecom/cdma-signal-generation-process/spreading-and-de-spreading) for more details.

a Simple example for parity checking, assume we send 8 Bits, 7 Bits data and 8th bit is parity check.
we send :
0110011X: X in this case is the parity checker, is 0 because we have 4 ones and 4 is even.
if there is a mistake in the data tranmitted and we receive for example this
11100110: Number of ones in the Byte Stream is 5 with a mistake in MSB. 5 should produce a parity bit of 1 because 5 is odd, but since the parity is 0, this means there is a mistake in the data transmitted. This is the simplest parity check used in serial data transfer. Error Correcting codes build on it.